# dockerでwebコンテナは立ち上がっているのにブラウザでlocalhostを確認すると「localhost からデータが送信されませんでした。」が表示される

Tags: docker, docker-compose

お世話になっております。

昨夜docker環境で　dbコンテナが立ち上がらない問題（解決済み）に直面したのですが、
今度はwebでlocalhostが表示されなくなってしまいました。

現状の状況を下記に書かせていただきます。
よろしくお願いします....。

#### docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build: ./docker/web
    container_name: test_web
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/test
    working_dir: /var/www/test
    privileged: true
    depends_on:
      - db
    (一部抜粋)
```

### Dockerfile

```
FROM amazonlinux:2

RUN yum -y update

RUN rm -rf /etc/localtime
RUN cp /usr/share/zoneinfo/Japan /etc/localtime

RUN yum install -y \
  sudo \
  wget \
  tar \
  unzip \
  yum-utils \
  git \
  vim \
  crontabs

RUN amazon-linux-extras install php8.0
RUN yum -y --enablerepo=amzn2extra-php8.0 install \
  php \
  php-cli \
  php-common \
  php-devel \
  php-fpm \
  php-gd \
  php-intl \
  php-json \
  php-mbstring \
  php-mcrypt \
  php-mysqlnd \
  php-pdo \
  php-xml

RUN yum install php-pear gcc make -y \
  && pecl install xdebug

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php \
  && mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer

RUN sudo amazon-linux-extras install nginx1.12 \
  && systemctl enable nginx.service \
  && systemctl enable php-fpm.service

ENV NODE_VERSION v16.6.1
ENV NVM_DIR /root/.nvm

RUN curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.8/install.sh | bash \
  && [ -s $NVM_DIR/nvm.sh ] && \. $NVM_DIR/nvm.sh \
  && nvm install $NODE_VERSION \
  && nvm alias default $NODE_VERSION \
  && nvm use default

ENV PATH $NVM_DIR/versions/node/$NODE_VERSION/bin:$PATH

RUN yum install -y https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql80-community-release-el7-5.noarch.rpm
RUN yum -y --enablerepo=mysql80-community install mysql-community-client

RUN mv /etc/nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf.org
RUN mv /etc/php.ini /etc/php.ini.org

COPY conf/www.conf    /etc/php-fpm.d/
COPY conf/conf.d/     /etc/nginx/conf.d/
COPY conf/nginx.conf  /etc/nginx/
COPY conf/php.ini     /etc/

RUN mkdir /run/httpd

CMD ["/sbin/init"]
```

### 実行コマンド

```
$ docker-compose build --no-cache
$ docker-compose up
$ docker-compose exec web bash
# composer install
# cp .env.example .env
# php artisan storage:link
# chmod 777 ./storage
# chmod 777 ./bootstrap/cache
```

### 問題が起きるまでにやったこと

- dbコンテナがdemonの問題で動かなくなったので
  「`chown mysql:mysql /var/run/mysqld`」を実行
- OSのアップデート
- dockerのアップデート

### 現状

- docker上は全てのコンテナがrunning中
- 各コンテナにも入れるがChromeで「localhost:8080」をみようとすると
  「llocalhost からデータが送信されませんでした。」が表示される
- 「`curl localhost:8080`」で確認したところ
  「`curl: (52) Empty reply from server`」と出力
- webコンテナ内で「`curl localhost:8080`」で確認したところ
  「 `curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8080 after 0 ms: Connection refused`」と出力
- 「 `cat /var/log/httpd/error_log` 」でエラーを確認

```
[Fri Jul 08 06:04:34.046176 2022] [suexec:notice] [pid 32] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Fri Jul 08 06:04:34.062713 2022] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 33] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Fri Jul 08 06:04:34.062844 2022] [http2:warn] [pid 33] AH10034: The mpm module (prefork.c) is not supported by mod_http2. The mpm determines how things are processed in your server. HTTP/2 has more demands in this regard and the currently selected mpm will just not do. This is an advisory warning. Your server will continue to work, but the HTTP/2 protocol will be inactive.
[Fri Jul 08 06:04:34.134886 2022] [core:error] [pid 33] (2)No such file or directory: AH00099: could not create /run/httpd/httpd.pid.xUvxAq
[Fri Jul 08 06:04:34.134923 2022] [core:error] [pid 33] AH00100: httpd: could not log pid to file /run/httpd/httpd.pid
[Fri Jul 08 06:04:45.026097 2022] [suexec:notice] [pid 34] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Fri Jul 08 06:04:45.042733 2022] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 35] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Fri Jul 08 06:04:45.042820 2022] [http2:warn] [pid 35] AH10034: The mpm module (prefork.c) is not supported by mod_http2. The mpm determines how things are processed in your server. HTTP/2 has more demands in this regard and the currently selected mpm will just not do. This is an advisory warning. Your server will continue to work, but the HTTP/2 protocol will be inactive.
[Fri Jul 08 06:04:45.054556 2022] [core:error] [pid 35] (2)No such file or directory: AH00099: could not create /run/httpd/httpd.pid.kFmi8f
[Fri Jul 08 06:04:45.054574 2022] [core:error] [pid 35] AH00100: httpd: could not log pid to file /run/httpd/httpd.pid
```

- 「mkdir /run/httpd」実行
- 「`docker-compose stop`」 後 「`docker-compose up`」
- 再びコンテナ内で「 `cat /var/log/httpd/error_log` 」

```
[Fri Jul 08 06:34:20.907690 2022] [suexec:notice] [pid 30] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Fri Jul 08 06:34:20.920239 2022] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 31] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Fri Jul 08 06:34:20.920397 2022] [http2:warn] [pid 31] AH10034: The mpm module (prefork.c) is not supported by mod_http2. The mpm determines how things are processed in your server. HTTP/2 has more demands in this regard and the currently selected mpm will just not do. This is an advisory warning. Your server will continue to work, but the HTTP/2 protocol will be inactive.
[Fri Jul 08 06:34:20.954746 2022] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 31] AH00163: Apache/2.4.53 () configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Jul 08 06:34:20.954780 2022] [core:notice] [pid 31] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd'
```

### 追記

OSのアップデートもしていたので追記します
OS：「Mac Monterey」
チップ：　「Apple M1」

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nginx パッケージのインストールと設定をした後、デーモンが起動されていないのが原因のように見えます。

過去の [類似質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/68641) の記述を参考にすると、Dockerfile の末尾辺りに以下の記述が必要かと思います。

```
ENTRYPOINT /usr/sbin/php-fpm && /usr/sbin/nginx -g "daemon off;"
```

Comment: ありがとうございます！！！無事ブラウザから確認できました！！！本当に感謝です。。。